# PHP - Read excel file

Tags: php, excel

I want to read an Excel file with PHP row by row because reading the entire file at once cause memory overflow.

I have searched a lot, but no luck until now.

I think PHPExcel library can read chunks of an excel file, when you implement the filter class, but each time it gets this chunk it reads the entire file, which is impossible in huge .xls files because of the time it will take.

Any help ?

Comment: Why not convert your xls file to cvs and read it line by line (with fopen/fgets)?

Comment: When you use "chunks" in PHPExcel, it __scans__ the entire file; it does not __load__ the entire file.... but what other of the PHPExcel memory-saving facilities such as cell caching are you using?

Comment: http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/349916

Comment: @Mark, sorry my fault, I meant scans the entire file.
The file can contain millions of rows. I need to parse it with one pass only over the file.
Isn't there a way, like reading the CSV files(fgetcsv) to read row by row ?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, how to do that ?

Comment: @MahmoudAslan: you can save/export your file directly with excel to .csv

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, I want this process to be automatic.
The client will upload a file xls, I want a PHP script to convert it to csv.

Comment: There isn't a way to read the file only one row at a time with PHPExcel (the structure of the BIFF file isn't simple like that, which is why you need a library like PHPExcel in the first place): Cell caching is the best option to reduce memory usage (SQLite is particularly efficient); and "read chunking" a secondary option, or reading a worksheet at a time - if the file has millions of rows, then it must be split over several worksheets - but when you're working with very large files, you need a reasonable amount of memory.

Answer (score 0):

This may be something that is totally out of question, but from the information that I get from your question the following seems like an obvious option, at least something to consider ...

I get the impression that this is a really big file that needs to be accessed often. So, I would just try to import its data in a database.

- I guess there is no need to explain that databases are masters in performance and caching.
- And it is still possible to export the contents of the database to an excel file afterwards.
- MySql works great with PHP and is certainly easier to access than an excel file. Most php hosting providers offer a MySql database by default with a PhpMyAdmin management tool.

**How to do it:**

- If you have PhpMyAdmin installed, then you can follow [these simple steps](http://webimpulse.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/hello-world/).
- If you have command-line access to the server then you can even import the file from commandline directly to a MySql database.

Comment: I can't import the data directly into the database, I must parse the file ask the client for some clarification about the fields in the file and also I must check the records for corrupted data ect..

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you need from your read Excel file is data, here is my way to read huge Excel files :

I install gnumeric on my server, ie with debian/ubuntu :
apt-get install gnumeric

Then the php calls to read my excel file and store it into a two dimensionnal data array are incredibly simple (dimensions are rows and cols) :

```
system("ssconvert \"$excel_file_name\" \"temp.csv\"");
$array = array_map("str_getcsv", file("temp.csv"));
```

Then I can do what I want with my array. This takes less than 10 seconds for a 10MB large xls file, the same time I would need to load the file on my favorite spreadsheet software !

*For very huge files, you should use fopen() and file_getcsv() functions and do what you have to do without storing data in a huge array to avoid storing the whole csv file in memory with the file() function. This will be slower, but will not eat all your server's memory !*

Comment: Thanks for reply, I know gnumeric, but I didn't like it because it is a Gnome project, so it needs gnome or some packages from it. I want an independent tool.
I already made my own library now, I only needed it before to save time.